# How to call a php site transmitting values via POST?

Tags: php, post

Let´s say I have an **index.php**:

```
<?php
    $currentUser = "Paedow";
?>
```

And I have an **user.php**:

```
<?php
    printf($_POST["currentUser"]);
?>
```

How can I submit the variable `$currentUser` to the **user.php** while calling it?

I tried this code, but this only submits the data without calling/viewing the page:

```
function PostToHost($host, $path, $referer, $data_to_send) {
  $fp = fsockopen($host, 80);
  fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
  fputs($fp, "Referer: $referer\r\n");
  fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
  fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($data_to_send) ."\r\n");
  fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  fputs($fp, $data_to_send);
  while(!feof($fp)) {
      $res .= fgets($fp, 128);
  }
  fclose($fp);

  return $res;
}
```

Comment: You'd be a lot happier just using cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it isn´t possible as I like; so I´m using [`Cookies`](http://php.net/Cookies).
Another option would be to use a [`Session`](http://php.net/Session).

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Use client-side javascript that will post your data, return the output so you can do with it what you want. See [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

### Option 2

Use server-side (like something that you use already) but instead of this use cURL to post your values. See [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `$data_to_send` would need to look like this:

```
currentUser=Paedow
```

That's what form-urlencoded data looks like.

However, can I suggest a different tack: it may be easier for you to use cURL to do a HTTP POST instead like so:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

(Keep in mind, I haven't tested that and just typed it in off the top of my head.)

Comment: i want to get to the **login.php** and not just to receive data from it

Comment: I want the **login.php** to be shown in the browser as **login.php**